# Matlab code for generating a particular class of matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to generate all square matrices of order n with given properties.

1. Matrices are symmetric.
2. Entries are 0 and 1.
3. Diagonal elements are zeros.

I am using Matlab2012b. Can you help me with the code?

I was trying to write it down. It needs a long sequences of for loops. Any simpler technique?

Comment: In order to answer your question you should provide what you are doing and what you would like to do. How are you creating matrices in matlab now?  What sort of inputs are you expecting and what type of outputs are you expecting?

Comment: Input is order of the matrices. Output will be all matrices of the particular class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
N = 4; %// matrix size
M = (N^2-N)/2; %// number of values to fill in each matrix
P = 2^M; %// number of matrices
x = dec2bin(0:P-1)-'0'; %// each row contains the values of a matrix, "packed" in a vector
result = NaN(N,N,P); %// preallocate
for k = 1:P
    result(:,:,k) = squareform(x(k,:)); %// unpack values
end
```

The matrices are `result(:,:,1)`,  `result(:,:,2)` etc.

Comment: nice use of `squareform` ;)

Comment: BTW you can skip the pre-allocation with `NaN` and loop from `P` to 1

Comment: @Shai Thanks! Yes, that could be faster